# How to update multiple columns of Dataframe from given set of maps in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have below dataframe

```
val df=Seq(("manuj","kumar","CEO","Info"),("Alice","Beb","Miniger","gogle"),("Ram","Kumar","Developer","Info Delhi")).toDF("fname","lname","designation","company")
```

or

```
+-----+-----+-----------+----------+
|fname|lname|designation|   company|
+-----+-----+-----------+----------+
|manuj|kumar|        CEO|      Info|
|Alice|  Beb|    Miniger|     gogle|
|  Ram|Kumar|  Developer|Info Delhi|
+-----+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Below is the given maps for individual column

```
val fnameMap=Map("manuj"->"Manoj")

val lnameMap=Map("Beb"->"Bob")

val designationMap=Map("Miniger"->"Manager")

val companyMap=Map("Info"->"Info Ltd","gogle"->"Google","Info Delhi"->"Info Ltd")
```

I also have list of columns which need to be updated so my requirement is that update all the columns of dataframe(df) which are in given list of columns using given maps.

```
val colList=Iterator("fname","lname","designation","company")
```

Output must be like

```
+-----+-----+-----------+--------+
|fname|lname|designation| company|
+-----+-----+-----------+--------+
|Manoj|kumar|        CEO|Info Ltd|
|Alice|  Bob|    Manager|  Google|
|  Ram|Kumar|  Developer|Info Ltd|
+-----+-----+-----------+--------+
```

Edit: Dataframe may have around 1200 columns and colList will have less than 1200 column names so I need to iterate over colList and update value of corresponding column from corresponding map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since DataFrames are immutable, in this example it can be processed progressively column by column, by creating a new DataFrame containing an intermediate column with replaced values, then renaming this column to initial name and finally overwriting the original DataFrame.

To achieve all this, several steps will be necessary.

First, we'll need a `udf` that returns a replacement value if it occurs in the provided map:

```
def replaceValueIfMapped(mappedValues: Map[String, String]) = udf((cellValue: String) =>
  mappedValues.getOrElse(cellValue, cellValue)
)
```

Second, we'll need a generic function that expects a DataFrame, a column name and its replacements map. This function produces a dataframe with a temporary column, containing replaced values, drops the original column, renames the temporary one to the original name and finally returns the produced DataFrame:

```
def replaceColumnValues(toReplaceDf: DataFrame, column: String, mappedValues: Map[String, String]): DataFrame = {
  val replacedColumn = column + "_replaced"
  toReplaceDf.withColumn(replacedColumn, replaceValueIfMapped(mappedValues)(col(column)))
    .drop(column)
    .withColumnRenamed(replacedColumn, column)
}
```

Third, instead of having an `Iterator` on column names for replacements, we'll use a `Map`, where each column name is associated with a replacements map:

```
val colsToReplace = Map("fname" -> fnameMap, 
  "lname" -> lnameMap, 
  "designation" -> designationMap, 
  "company" -> companyMap)
```

Finally, we can call `foldLeft` on this map in order to execute all the replacements:

```
val replacedDf = colsToReplace.foldLeft(sourceDf){ case(alreadyReplaced, toReplace) =>
  replaceColumnValues(alreadyReplaced, toReplace._1, toReplace._2)
}
```

`replacedDf` now contains the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

To make the lookup dynamic at this level, you'll probably need to change the way you map your values to make then dynamically searchable. I would make maps of maps, with keys being the names of the columns, as expected to be passed in:

```
val fnameMap=Map("manuj"->"Manoj")
val lnameMap=Map("Beb"->"Bob")
val designationMap=Map("Miniger"->"Manager")
val companyMap=Map("Info"->"Info Ltd","gogle"->"Google","Info Delhi"->"Info Ltd")

val allMaps = Map("fname"->fnameMap,
                  "lname" -> lnameMap,
                  "designation" -> designationMap,
                  "company" -> companyMap)
```

This may make sense as the maps are relatively small, but you may need to consider using broadcast variables.

You can then dynamically look up based on field names.

*** [ if you've seen that my scala code is bad, it's because it is. So here's a java version for you to translate] ***

```
List<String> allColumns = Arrays.asList(dataFrame.columns());

df
.map(row ->
    //this rewrites the row (that's a warning)
    RowFactory.create(
        allColumns.stream()
        .map(dfColumn -> {
                 if(!colList.contains(dfColumn)) {
                     //column not requested for mapping, use old value
                     return row.get(allColumns.indexOf(dfColumn));
                 } else {
                     Object colValue = 
                             row.get(allColumns.indexOf(dfColumn))
                     // in case of [2], you'd have to call:
                     //row.get(colListToDFIndex.get(dfColumn))

                     //Modified value
                     return allMaps.get(dfColumn)   
                      //Assuming strings, you may need to cast
                     .getOrDefault(colValue, colValue);
                 }
             })
         .collect(Collectors.toList())
         .toArray()
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I get dataframe as input so I can't change dataframe to rdd and no of columns in dataframe may be 1200. so I need to update only columns which are in colList Iterator

Comment: @ManojKumarDhakd Made an edit... although that gives you a bit of java fun :-)